# OneLogin + Dynamics 365 Authenitcation via Code

Tags: dynamics-crm, saml, microsoft-dynamics, onelogin, dynamics-365

Our developer team is trying to execute code that pass static credentials to Dynamics 365 for authentication to execute a web services link:

1) When we connect to the web services link ourcompany.api.crm.dynamics.com/.../Organization.svc via a web browser it auths via OneLogin & authenticates the currently logged in User

2) We want to pass a specific static credential to the web services link

3) When we pass credentials via code we get an error “The authentication endpoint Username was not found on the configured Secure Token Service”

Several web articles point to an ADFS configuration error or certificate error; however we do not have an ADFS server. We only tie in via OneLogin for SSO/SAML

How can we successfully pass this code through (Static User/PW) to OLI (or possibly O365 – Redirection/Bypass OLI) for authentication?”

Answer (score 1):

Are you running in the Sandbox? If so you may running into this.

[Web access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx#Web%20access)

> Sandboxed plug-ins and custom workflow activities can access the
>   network through the HTTP and HTTPS protocols. This capability provides
>   support for accessing popular web resources like social sites, news
>   feeds, web services, and more. The following web access restrictions
>   apply to this sandbox capability.
>
> - Anonymous authentication is supported and recommended. There is no provision for prompting the logged on user for credentials or saving
>     those credentials.

Comment: The .Net plugin code is running in Visual Studio and is attempting to connect to our Dynamics Sandbox. Do you have a link to the info about Anonymous authentication?

Comment: @Michael, when you say `plugin code is running in Visual Studio`, what specifically do you mean? (As by default you cant run a CRM plugin outside of CRM - so presumably you have a bit of magic or I have misunderstood what you are actually doing).

Comment: Hi James, sorry shouldnt have said "Plugin". We are developing Web Methods. Forgive me as I am not the developer, just the PM trying to get this issue resolved.

Comment: @Michael, you should have a look at getting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example posted then if you want to get help on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the advice James. I'll work on getting an example as suggested.